# Concat inside a WHERE clause in postgres

Tags: postgresql, concatenation

I have a question about concat function in PostgreSQL.

This sentence works well in MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM words
 WHERE CONCAT (word,' ',gender,' ',semantic) LIKE '%"+value+"%'.
```

Value is a variable that is changed inside my Java program.

But I need the same working in postgresql. How kann I concatenate inside the WHERE clause, using postgres, considering the variable "value"  that will have its value changed ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In Postgresql you concatenate using the following syntax:

```
(users.first_name || ' ' || users.last_name)
```

**Reference**: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html

Comment: I know that in postgres we use || to concatenate, but I kann not translate the same I have working in MySQL to Postgresql. I find nothing about concatenate inside the Where clause.

Comment: @user2233540 Concatenation in `WHERE` clause works in the same way. In your case it will be something like `WHERE (word||' '||gender||' '||semantic) LIKE '%"+value+"%'`

Comment: Ok, thanks you all! In postguesql it does not work like it does in MySQL. I had to use a WHERE word LIKE '%"+value+"%' OR gender '%"+value+"%'... to emulate the same behavior.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use this for postgresql:

```
concat_ws(' ', campo1, campo2) like '%value%'
```

Note that there is a space between single quotes